# Proguard keep methods referenced from external jar

Tags: java, android, jar, google-play-services, proguard

I'm trying to figure out how to use proguard to reduce the method count in a jar file. My issue is that I have other jar files that reference code in my target jar and I need to ensure the code referenced by the external jars is kept. I'm new to android development and this is my first time fiddling with proguard so bear with me.

My target jar pulls in the Google Play Services code and ontop of the default proguard config, I use keep lines like this:

```
-keep class com.blah.blah.** { *; }
```

to keep my target files and whatever they reference from being removed. I have tried using `-libraryjars` to link in the external jars and then use similar keep lines to hold onto the target classes from the external jar that would be referencing the Google Play Services code. But that doesn't make much sense and obviously did not work.

> NOTE: These jar files do need to be kept separate as they are being used to construct different Adobe AIR ANEs :/

Any help, pointers, or suggestions would be much appreciated!